# Dynamically adding radio button list according to string values in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, listview, radio-button, radio-group

I have seen that this can be done for **ListView** where you can just grab the string-array values from **strings.xml** and populate the ListView **dynamically** depending on the number of listed items.

But I was wondering if the same feat can be done using Radio Buttons and Radio Button Group?

I've come across this piece of code

```
RadioGroup rgp= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
      radioButton.setText("new"+i);
      radioButton.setId("rbtn"+i);
      rprms= new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);

  }
```

And was wondering how I can modify the `radioButton.setId("rbtn"+i)` to grab string-array values from the **strings.xml** file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String[] foo_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array);` to read array from strings.xml. Then loop through the obtained array.